# Remove responsiveness from the theme?

Tags: responsive-design

How to remove responsiveness from the theme.
I have done the following for this
1. removed all the media queries from the style-sheet.
2. remove meta viewport 
but it can not remove the responsiveness and website still zoom in the mobile devices .

what is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

I Feel you need to check initial scale value of your website, you need to check this code once in you page :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

place this code in your head tag.

Hope it's work.

Comment: i have included this one but the problum still the same